# Criminal Jack is here to haunt

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Solve This Rebus, the correct answer is an English phrase.

> JACK THE RI_ _ER

All the best :)

Comment: Will probably be much easier for speakers of British English.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about

> **No peace for the wicked** (no Ps, Jack the Ripper could be considered wicked, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

#### This is not the intended answer(my achievement)...confirmed by OP

There had been a movie named

> Jack the Ripper

So the phrase can be

> **Pee in space**

or maybe

> **Pee in space suit**

Comment: 'Pee in Space-suit' would have been funnier, but sorry. Not Correct ;)

Answer (score 9):

It may be...

> Rest In Peace

Because:

> Only rest of the word is 'P's only, and Jack is the **RIP**per..

Comment: It clearly is correct

Comment: No it is not. The name holds a significance along with the way it is displayed.

Comment: I am hoping it wont be "Peace Out" either based on your comment.

Comment: This one is my favorite tbh

Answer (score 5):

I think it may be

> No peace for the wicked

Comment: already guessed...

Comment: I'm too slow :)

Comment: correct one @Tom

Answer (score 5):

So sorry officer, can't fully recollect his name 'cause...

> ...he scared the *P's* outta me!!!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

> **Peace in Space** (http://www.peaceinspace.com/)

Argument:

> 1. The space in JACK THE RI__ER corresponds to two Ps, which sounds like PEACE
>  2. The outer space treaty (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty) is sometimes called PEACE IN SPACE

Comment: Close. Think about the name too.

Answer (score 4):

I think it will be

> **The missing piece ( The missing Ps)**

Since

> It should be JACK THE RIPPER with two Ps missing (JACK THE RI__PER).

and

> "A Piece Of Apron" is known as the missing piece in the Jack the Ripper case file.

Comment: the missing PEACE is relevent to the answer. But nice one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Shooting in the dark here:

> JACK THE RISKER
>  JACK THE RINGER
>  JACK THE RIGGER

Comment: that would be 'RIDDLER' and nope, not correct!

Comment: @Prashant. true. Sorry about my English :)

Comment: It's actually a Three's Company reference.  The character Jack was played by John Ri**tt**er.

Answer (score 1):

Will be two PP's

> Peace in Space will fit

Comment: Is that a common English phrase? I've never heard it.